# Laravel get redirect URL

Tags: php, laravel

I have problems with getting Laravel URL.

I have one page that if user is not logged in, it redirect user to wrong url and it's giving an error.

I'm using `redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());` to get back user where he was on page after login, so somehow I have to write code that will check what is the redirect URL, and if it's the URL that will give an error,

I know what is the URL, it must redirect user to another URL that I need to set.

I tried different methods taking 
`$this->redirectPath() == 'here goes the url'`

and like 
`redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath()) == 'again url here'`

But nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return Redirect::intended('here goes the url');
```

Or

```
return Redirect::intended();
```

`intended()` checks if the session index url.intended exists and redirects to it by default or else redirect to $default='/' which can be overwritten.

Comment: Sorry I don't think that is solution for my question. I have to write if the url that I give is actual redirect URL it must return what I set, but in else method I have to set by default as it is (redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath())

Comment: I tried like redirect()->intended()->getTargetURL() , and it's giving URL only, how to get path?

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand what `redirect()->intended()` actually does.

It looks for a session variable named `url.intended` like `session()->pull('url.intended')` (note that `pull()` will remove the variable after this call, which is handy because you usually only need this variable once).

This variable is currently only set when you call `redirect()->guest('/yourpath')` (it will set your current URL as the `url.intended`), unless you manually set it in your own logic using `session()->put('url.intended')`.

So the most obvious way to use this is to use `redirect()->guest('/login')`, and then after the user has successfully logged in you may use `redirect()->intended()` (without parameter) to redirect the user back to the page that originally sent him to the login page.